# C Macros: replacing C header includes that have angle brackets

Tags: c++, c, macros, include, preprocessor

I'm using this library in a PlatformIO project https://registry.platformio.org/libraries/joaolopesf/RemoteDebug

I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/JoaoLopesF/RemoteDebug/issues/87)
where the library has an obsolete include `#include <hwcrypto/sha.h>` that causes a compile error.

The solution is replacing this with the newer include `<esp32/sha.h>`.

While this is a valid solution, I don't like to have to edit library code to do it.

The question then, is if I can fix this from user code somehow?
something like `#define <hwcrypto/sha.h> <esp32/sha.h>`.

(That specific macro throws a different compile error).

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution at the source level to replace the include file name. Yet you can probably use a work around using the include path:

Run these commands from the main source directory:

```sh
mkdir compat
mkdir compat/hwcrypto
echo '#include <esp32/sha.h>' > compat/hwcrypto/sha.h
```

Then you can compile the library source unmodified passing `-Icompat` as an extra compilation option.  You can use a different path for the `compat` directory to avoid modifying the source tree.

Answer (score 0):

> if I can fix this from user code somehow?

No. You have to edit the source file.